# Restricting the Courant Bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, differential-forms, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a manifold and $E$ be a subbundle of $\mathbb{T}M:= TM\oplus T^{*}M$ such that $\Gamma(E)$ is closed under the Courant bracket. The Courant bracket $[[\cdot,\cdot]]$ is an operation on $\Gamma(\mathbb{T}M)$ given by
$$
[[X\oplus\alpha,Y\oplus\beta]] = [X,Y]\oplus(L_{X}\alpha - i_{Y}d\beta),
$$
where $L_{X}, i_{Y}, d$ are the usual Lie derivative, insertion and exterior differential, respectively.

**Q:** Suppose that $\sigma,\tau\in\Gamma(\mathbb{T}M)$ have the following property: there exists a (regular,embedded) submanifold $N$ of $M$ such that $\sigma_{p},\tau_{p}\in E_{p}$ $\forall p\in N$.

Is it true that $[[\sigma,\tau]]_{p}\in E_{p}$ $\forall p\in N$?

This property holds, for example, in the case of vector fields and their Lie bracket: if two vector fields are tangent to a submanifold, then their Lie bracket is also tangent to it.

My guess is that this is true since the Courant bracket satisfy the folllwing property:
$$
[[\sigma,f\tau]] = f[[\sigma,\tau]] + L_{\mathrm{pr}_{TM}(\sigma)}f\cdot\tau,
$$
where $\mathrm{pr}_{TM}:\mathbb{T}M\rightarrow TM$ is the canonical projection $X\oplus\alpha\mapsto X$.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of "restriction of $E$ to $N$"?

Comment: @JohnMa, done. Such restriction is just thinking about the points $p$ of $N$ as elements of $M$. Then consider the space $E_{p}$ for each $p\in N$ and add them together to construct the bundle $E_{N}$.

Comment: This seems trivial as written: the restriction of any section of $\mathbb{T} M$ to $N$ will be a section of $E_N$. Do you mean instead to define $E_N$ as $\mathbb{T} N$, so that if $v \oplus \mu \in E_N$ then we must have $v \in  TN$ and $\mu \in T^* N$? This would seem to be more analogous to your Lie bracket example.

Comment: Is not that trivial. 
The problem is that $\sigma,\tau$ are not sections of $E$, the only thing we can assume is that they take values on $E$ at the points $p\in N$. Also, we know that $\Gamma(E)$ is closed under the Courant bracket.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you were taking $E$ to be a (proper) subbundle. Even then, it seems that $\Gamma(E)$ being closed under the bracket is all you need - this tells you that $[[\sigma, \tau]] \in \Gamma(E)$, which implies $[[\sigma, \tau]]_N \in \Gamma(E_N)$ by your definition of $E_N$, since sections of $E_N$ are just restrictions of sections of $E$ to $N$.

Comment: To clarify the point I'm trying to make: by your definitions we have  $E_N|_p = E_p \subset T_p M \oplus T_p M^*$, whereas I think you might actually mean $E_N|_p = (T_p N \oplus T_p N^*) \cap E_p$. Your question at the moment is not analogous to $[\cdot,\cdot] : \Gamma(TN)\times\Gamma(TN) \to \Gamma(TN)$ as you want it to be, but to the more trivial $[\cdot,\cdot]:\Gamma(TM|_N) \times \Gamma(TM|_N) \to \Gamma(TM|_N)$. As written there's also no reason to suppose $\sigma,\tau$ have the restriction property, either, since *all* sections do.

Comment: You can't actually define ${E_N}|_p = (T_pN \oplus T_pN^*)\cap E_p$, because $T_pN^*$ is not a subspace of $T_pM^*$; it's a quotient space. So it's not clear there's a meaningful question one can ask here. (As @AnthonyCarapetis pointed out, if you just define ${E_N}|_p=E_p$, the result is trivially true by the definition of the bracket.)

Comment: Facts:

$\sigma$ and $\tau$ are sections of $\mathbb{T}M$, not of $E$.

$E$ is closed under $[[\cdot,\cdot]]$.

For each $p\in N$, $\sigma_{p},\tau_{p}\in E_{p}$ ONLY when $p\in N$.

*Question*: Is it true that $[[\sigma,\tau]]_{p}\in E_{p}$ when $p\in N$?

The bracket cannot be pointwise defined.

Comment: *Answer:* It is not necessarily true...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not necessarily true...

Take a basis of (local) sections $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{k}\}$ of $E$ and complete it to a basis $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{k+l}\}$ of $\mathbb{T}M$. Then, every $\sigma\in\Gamma(\mathbb{T}M)$ such that $\sigma_{p}\in E_{p}$ for all $p\in N$ is of the form
$$
\sigma = \sum_{i=1}^{k+l} f^{i}e_{i},
$$
where $f^{i}(p)=0$ $\forall p\in N$ and $i>k$.

Assume that $E$ has the property as stated in the question. Then, $[[e_{j},\sigma]]_{p}\in E_{p}$ for all $p\in N$ and $j\leq k$. By $\mathbb{R}$-linearity and applying the property of the Courant bracket presented in the question, we get
\begin{align}
[[e_{j},\sigma]]&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+l}f^{i}[[e_{j},e_{i}]]+L_{a(e_{j})}f^{i}\cdot e_{i}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k}f^{i}[[e_{j},e_{i}]]+L_{a(e_{j})}f^{i}\cdot e_{i} + \sum_{i=k+1}^{k+l}f^{i}[[e_{j},e_{i}]]+L_{a(e_{j})}f^{i}\cdot e_{i}.
\end{align}
Since $j\leq k$ and $e_{i}\in\Gamma(E)$ $\forall i\leq k$, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}f^{i}[[e_{j},e_{i}]]+L_{a(e_{j})}f^{i}\cdot e_{i}\in\Gamma(E).
$$
On the other hand, for $i>k$ and $p\in N$, we have $f^{i}(p)[[e_{j},e_{i}]]_{p}=0$. Furthermore, since $\{e_{i}\}_{i=1}^{k+l}$ is a basis such that it extends a basis of $\Gamma(E)$, it follows that $L_{a(e_{j})}f^{i}(p)$ must be equal to zero for all $p\in N$. Since $\sigma$ is arbitrary, then $f^{i}$ is arbitrary. Hence, we conclude that $e_{j}$ has the following property: *For all $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $f|_{N}=0$, we have $L_{a(e_j)}f|_{N}=0$*.

In other words, $a(e_{j})$ must be a vector field in $M$ which is tangent to the submanifold $N$ for all $j\leq k$.

**Conclusion:** A necessary condition to have the property of the question is: For every $p\in N$ and $\sigma\in E_{p}$, we must have $a(\sigma)\in T_{p}N$.

For sufficiency, we must ask further *compatibility conditions* on $E$ and $N$, because of the non-skew-symmetry of the Courant bracket.